# How to disable DelicateCoroutinesApi annotation in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin Coroutines 1.5+ brings the new `DelicateCoroutinesApi` annotation. How can I disable it in Android Studio?
I tried File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections but I did not find the inspection in the list.